# Correct XMPP message to use for broadcasting a query

Tags: xmpp, libjingle

I am trying to use Google's libjingle framework and need to broadcast a query from a client to other signed-in clients.

Is the correct way to do this with the IQ protocol (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0099.html), the presence protocol (http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html) or just by looping through the relevant clients and sending a direct message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly [XEP-0099](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0099.html) is deferred since 2003 (as per the red text at the top), I know no implementations of it, I really don't think it's what you are looking for.

Secondly, for `<iq/>` stanzas in general, you cannot broadcast them. They are a [one-to-one request-and-response mechanism](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-semantics-iq). One request returns exactly one response (or error), and broadcasting would break that rule. To broadcast some information use a [`<message/>`](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-semantics-message) or perhaps even [`<presence/>`](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-semantics-presence). If you need to *request* information from a series of JIDs, `<iq type="get">` probably is indeed the way to do it.